# Is there a way to make text appear after 5 seconds?

Tags: html, css, animation

I've tried searching for a way to make text appear after 10 seconds. I'm creating a loading screen for a forum I'm working on. I need to make text appear after 5 seconds of loading that says Continue, this of course is going to be a button/link. I've tried using css to animate the text to appear after 5 secs.

```
animation: 5 secs;
```

but this doesn't work for some reason. I would also appreciate help in this.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation

Comment: You are doing everything almost right, just change 'secs' to 's', e.g. animation: 5s

Answer (score 0):

Animation delay should work

```
{ animation-delay: 5s; }
```

Comment: Sorry,  but that doesn't work, for now I've made it so I'm fading it in, its working for now.